# my code doesn't work anymore but i haven't changed it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

i created several months ago a script to publish assignments for my students in google classroom.the code is the following

```
function createTrigger() { 
  // Trigger every day at 9
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('pubblicavideo')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(9)
      .everyDays(1) // Frequency is required if you are using atHour() or nearMinute()
      .create();
}

function onOpen() { 
  //aggiunge il bottone autotrigger con run e stop all'apertura del documento spreadsheet
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  ui.createMenu("Auto Trigger")
    .addItem("Run","runAuto")
    .addItem("Stop","deleteTrigger")
    .addToUi();
}

function runAuto() { 
  
  // resets the loop counter if it's not 0
  refreshUserProps(); 
   // clear out the sheet
  clearData();  
  // create trigger to run program automatically
  createTrigger();
}

function refreshUserProps() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('loopCounter', 0);
  userProperties.setProperty('contarighe', 1);
}



function deleteTrigger() {
  
  // Loop over all triggers and delete them
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}

function pubblica(k)
{
  var corso = Classroom.Courses.get(XXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
  var foglio = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var linkini = foglio.getRange("C709:C3014");
  var titolini = foglio.getRange("B709:B3014");
  var autorini = foglio.getRange("A709:A3014");
  var cell = linkini.getCell(k, 1);
  var cella = titolini.getCell(k, 1);
  var cello = autorini.getCell(k, 1);
  var link = cell.getValue();
  var titolo = cella.getValue();
  var autore = cello.getValue();
  var courseWork = {
  'title': titolo,
  'description': autore,
  'materials': [
     {'link': { "url": link}}    
],
  'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',
  'state': 'PUBLISHED',
}
Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork,XXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
}

function clearData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  
  // clear out the matches and output sheets
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > 1) {
    sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,1).clearContent();
  }
}



function pubblicavideo()
{
  var pezzialgiorno = 3;   //numero di pezzi da pubblicare ogni giorno
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  
  
   var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var loopCounter = Number(userProperties.getProperty('loopCounter'));
  var contarighe = Number(userProperties.getProperty('contarighe'));
  // put some limit on the number of loops
  // could be based on a calculation or user input
  // using a static number in this example
  var limit = 2301;
  
  // if loop counter < limit number, run the repeatable action
  if (loopCounter < limit) {
    
    // see what the counter value is at the start of the loop
    Logger.log(loopCounter);
    
    // do stuff
   for (var i=0; i<pezzialgiorno; i++)
   {
     pubblica(contarighe);
     contarighe++;
   }
     // increment the properties service counter for the loop
    loopCounter +=1;
    userProperties.setProperty('loopCounter', loopCounter);
    userProperties.setProperty('contarighe', contarighe);
    
    // see what the counter value is at the end of the loop
    Logger.log(loopCounter);
    Logger.log(contarighe);
  }
  
  // if the loop counter is no longer smaller than the limit number
  // run this finishing code instead of the repeatable action block
  else {
    
    // Log message to confirm loop is finished
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue("Finished");
    Logger.log("Finished");
    
     // delete trigger because we've reached the end of the loop
    // this will end the program
    deleteTrigger();  
  }
}
```

where i put the XXXXXXXXXXX there is the course ID.
the script is attached to a spreadsheet with 3 columns that have title, author and youtube link and the assignment is one of these videos put there as a link attached to the material. the script should publish every day at 9:00 a.m. 3 of the youtube videos in 3 different materials running down the list in the spreadsheet

when i try to execute the function called pubblicavideo it says

GoogleJsonResponseException: Chiamata API a classroom.courses.courseWork.create non riuscita con errore: Invalid value at 'course_work.description' (TYPE_STRING), 883 (riga 69, file "Codice")

i think the translation in english goes something like

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.create didn't work with error: Invalid value at 'course_work.description' (TYPE_STRING), 883 (row 69, file "Code")

this very script worked perfectly until the 13th of august. i don't know if there were any changes in google classroom scripts.

anyone of you knows how to make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The issue seems to be that at some point, the type of the value obtained from `autorini.getCell(k, 1).getValue()` is not a string which is causing the error.*

#### Steps to Solve:

In `pubblicavideo()`, the function `pubblica()` is called inside a loop with the variable `contarighe` passed. The value of this gets put into `k` for each run of `pubblica`.

These are the lines that are problematic:

```js
var autorini = foglio.getRange("A709:A3014");
var cello = autorini.getCell(k, 1);
var autore = cello.getValue();
```

You will need to check the value of `autore` before you make the request to `Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create()`.

[As per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#CourseWork) on the `CourseWork` Resource, the value of `description` should be of type `String`.

When creating the coursework object:

```
var courseWork = {
    'title': titolo,
    'description': autore,
    'materials': [
      {'link': { "url": link}}    
    ],
    'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',
    'state': 'PUBLISHED',
  }
```

The value of `autore` must reflect this. Make sure that at whatever point in the loop your code is halting, your sheet value is both of type String, and being retrieved correctly.

#### References:

- [REST Resource: courses.courseWork | Classroom API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork)

Comment: thank you very much, i checked and in the file there was one author that was a band called like a number (883). i added some letters before it and it started working again ^_^